# Change color of button on press and revert back to original color when press released flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have two radio buttons in a row. I want to change the colour of the first button when it is pressed to something else and if the second button is pressed the first button should go back to the default colour and the second button should go to the new colour.  I am doing this by writing the following code. But both buttons are changing colour together. Both are becoming green on press even if I press a single button.

Button 1:

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;

Widget startupButton() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width * 0.45,

        child: RaisedButton(
          color: isButtonPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isButtonPressed =!isButtonPressed;
            });
          },

          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Text('Startup Pack',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.black)),
              ),
              Text('Introductory Offer',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black)),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Text(
                        "\$$dollars",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Text(
                        "\$$dollars2",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: primaryColor),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),

              Text(
                "Per year",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: blackColor),
              ),
              Text(
                "Billed anually",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: blackColor),
              ),
            ],
          ),


        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Button 2:

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;
Widget freeButton() {
      return
        ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,

          child: RaisedButton(
            color: isButtonPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isButtonPressed =!isButtonPressed;
              });
            },


            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Text('Stunning Solo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color: Colors.black)),
                ),
                Text('Free Forever', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.black)),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Text(
                          "\$$dollars3",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: blackColor),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),

                      ]),
                ),

                Text(
                  "Free forever",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: blackColor),
                ),

              ],
            ),


          ),

        ),
      );


    }
```

Comment: Use animated container

Comment: Please provide a errorless code or complete code

Comment: @evan this is complete code

Comment: I am getting a lot of error, by the way, do you need to change the color on tap event?

Comment: @evan yes sorry I have corrected the code. Yes, colour change on tap event and when I tap the other button the first one should go back yo the default colour.

Comment: @ajay131, still error in your code, no worry, i have send you a demo code for your understanding, you can check if it works for you.

Comment: ok i got it, wait a moment'

Comment: @evan I have updated the fully working code, please check now

Comment: @ajay131 do you check the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool button1 = false;
bool button2 = false;

class Page0 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page0State createState() => _Page0State();
}

class _Page0State extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        startupButton(context, setState),
        freeButton(context, setState)
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget startupButton(context, setState) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: button1 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            button1 = true;
            button2 = false;
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text('Startup Pack',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
            ),
            Text('Introductory Offer',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "\$dollars",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                          color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Text(
                      "\$dollars2",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
            Text(
              "Per year",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
            ),
            Text(
              "Billed anually",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget freeButton(context, setState) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 150,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: button2 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            button1 = false;
            button2 = true;
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text('Stunning Solo',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: button2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
            ),
            Text('Free Forever',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: button2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "\$dollars3",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: button2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                  ]),
            ),
            Text(
              "Free forever",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 13,
                  color: button2 ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Fantastic it works. Can you please also tell me how can I change text also? Form black  (unpressed) to white(pressed)

Comment: accepted. There are multiple texts in one button. Please can you demonstrate the code?

Comment: I have edited the code again,
`color: button1 ? Colors.white : Colors.black`, it is if clause actually, you can use it anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221206/discussion-between-ajay131-and-evan).